# using apply with a class function to create new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a class function to every row in my dataframe. The code I have looks like below.

```
myCls = MyClass(0.123, True)

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: myCls.delta(x.pressure, x.atmos), axis=1)
```

I get the error message,

> NameError: name 'myCls' is not defined'

Am I not able to use my class function with apply?

Comment: have you tried mycls(x.pressure, x.atmos) instead  of mycls.delta()

Comment: @tyasird the class is intialised with different variables to what is passed to the delta function

Comment: Is your class called `mycls` or `myCls` ?  Note the capital letter `C` in the error message.

Comment: @SeaBean apologies that was a typo, have corrected my post thanks

Comment: Couldn't reproduce.